# How to apply counter and most_common to dataframe colum for each row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

As in the title, i would like to find top  100 words for each value inside the column.

I would like to be able to see top 100 words (highest frequency) in each row of the column in the dataframe. So technically the frequency of each row is separate to the other rows.

[image]

i would like to grab in the form of an example below:

[('http', 1059), ('coronaviru', 454), ('covid', 430), ('peopl', 120), ('time', 71), ('home', 67), ('amp', 58), ('stay', 55), ('day', 52), ('work', 52), ('pandem', 48), ('die', 44), ('countri', 42)]

if it is saved in the dataframe as such it would be great but in a list of list is also fine as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly I think you are looking for [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `sort = True`

An example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [['a','a','b','b','b','c'], ['d','d','e','e','f']]})

df

    col
0   [a, a, b, b, b, c]
1   [d, d, e, e, f]

df_dict = pd.DataFrame({'freq':df['col'].apply(lambda l : list(pd.Series(l).value_counts(sort = True).to_dict().items()))})
```

gives:

```
df_dict


    freq
0   [(b, 3), (a, 2), (c, 1)]
1   [(d, 2), (e, 2), (f, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using 'collections.Counter'?

```
from collections import Counter
df['final_tokens'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1))
```

If you want top `N` not just `1`, then use `.most_common(N)`

**Note**: This returns an `pandas.core.series.Series`, not datafram or list. You can always `.to_frame()` a `pd.Series`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def freq_dict(word_list):
    d = dict((i, word_list.count(i)) for i in word_list)          #Counting frequency and storing in a dictionary
    d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)     #Sorting the dictionary in descending order
    return d[:100]                                                #Returning the top 100 values

df['freq'] = df.final_tokens.apply(lambda x : freq_dict(x))       #Applying the function to get a new column in the dataframe containing dictionaries
```